# How delete all files in a directory but specific file names listed in a text file

Tags: loops, batch-file, text, directory

I have a folder named `Demos1` with files inside that all have a `.replay` extension.

I have a batch script in parent folder of `Demos1` as well as a file that has the names of the files i ONLY want to keep in a text file named `namediff.txt`.

I wants to recursiveley scan each file name in `namediff.txt` against the files found inside of the directory and if the file names (one per line) in `namediff.txt` does not match a file found in the directory, delete that file in `Demos1` and leave only the file names that did match in the txt file.

This is what I have so far.

```
PUSHD "%~dp0Demos1"

:--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN ('DIR /B "*.replay"') DO (
    FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%G IN ('%%~nxA') DO (
        IF NOT "%%~nxA"=="%%~nxG" ECHO DEL "%%~nxG"
    )
)
```

Comment: Are the filenames in `namediff.txt` simply `name.ext`? Would your batch simply delete all files in `demos1` that do **not** appear in `namediff.txt` ?

Comment: Yes the files in namediff.txt are found in the directory. I only want to keep the files in in the directory that match the names found in namediff.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN ('DIR /B /a-d "*.replay" ^|findstr /x /i /v /g:namediff.txt') DO echo del "%%A"
```

Should do that. `Findstr` finds lines that `/x` exactly match `/i` case-insensitive `/g:filecontainingstringstomatch` and `/v` produces **non**-matches to the list of files generated by the `dir`.

The `^` is required to escape the pipe, which tells `cmd` that the pipe is part of the command to be executed, not the `for`.

The /a-d excludes directory-names matching - just a belt-and-braces approach.

The `del` is simply `echo`ed for testing purposes. Remove the `echo` keyword when verified to delete the files.

Comment: I modified this to suit my needs. Thank you.